# Blender is laggy when using Grease Pencil with long animation

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, layers, draw-mode

My laptop is i7 12700h Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti, with Blender 3.5 on Windows 11, but it is pretty laggy in Blender especially now because I'm working on a project with a lot of frames. Specifically Grease Pencil 2D animation – it's 10000 frames long and I've reached frame 7200, but it is really laggy now. Like when I want to erase, it takes a while and it starts to not respond. When opening and closing the layers it takes a while.
I've tried and watched a lot of videos and none of them actually worked it, although it helped a little bit, I guess.